# Filter and pick values from an array of objects and copy to other array of objects

Tags: arrays, filter, javascript-objects, intersection

What I'm trying to achieve is bring information from one array of objects to another array of objects, find the match that would be the last4 numbers of a card, extract from that array the key with values and bring them to the other array of objects.

```
const array1 = [
    {
        card: {
            expiryDate: '2025-06-30',
            isPinSet: true,
            issuedDate: '2021-06-02',
            lastNumbers: '2377',
            status: 'ACTIVE',
            type: 'PHYSICAL'
        }
    },
    {
        card: {
            expiryDate: '2024-11-30',
            isPinSet: true,
            issuedDate: '2020-12-14',
            lastNumbers: '7231',
            status: 'TERMINATED',
            type: 'PHYSICAL',
            terminationDate: '2021-06-02'
        }
    }
];

const array2 = [
    {
        dateCreated: '2021-06-02T11:14:27.348Z[UTC]',
        link: 'juan ',
        reason: 'lost card',
        reissueRequest: {
            link: 'juan ',
            reason: 'lost card',
            cardType: 'PHYSICAL',
            personId: '2576890',
            adminUser: 'juan@hotmail.com',
            changePAN: true,
            lastNumbers: '7231',
            maintainPIN: false
        },
        reissuedCard: {
            state: 'UNACTIVATED',
            cardId: null,
            cardType: 'PHYSICAL',
            isPinSet: true,
            lastFour: '2377',
            dateCreated: '2021-06-02',
            expirationDate: '2025-06-30'
        }
    }
];
```

I was expecting some like this:

```
const result = [
    {
        card: {
            expiryDate: '2025-06-30',
            isPinSet: true,
            issuedDate: '2021-06-02',
            lastNumbers: '2377',
            status: 'ACTIVE',
            type: 'PHYSICAL',
            reissuedCard: {
                state: 'UNACTIVATED',
                cardId: null,
                cardType: 'PHYSICAL',
                isPinSet: true,
                lastFour: '2377',
                dateCreated: '2021-06-02',
                expirationDate: '2025-06-30'
            }
        }
    },
    {
        card: {
            expiryDate: '2024-11-30',
            isPinSet: true,
            issuedDate: '2020-12-14',
            lastNumbers: '7231',
            status: 'TERMINATED',
            type: 'PHYSICAL',
            terminationDate: '2021-06-02'
        }
    }
];
```

I was thinking first filtering, then map it but is not working very well.

any ideas on how to achieve this?

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Does the below answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over `array2` to store the `reissuedCard`  and the `lastFour` in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
2. Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), iterate over `array1` and combine with the element its matching item in the map if exists

```js
const 
  array1 = [
    { card: { expiryDate: '2025-06-30', isPinSet: true, issuedDate: '2021-06-02', lastNumbers: '2377', status: 'ACTIVE', type: 'PHYSICAL' } },
    { card: { expiryDate: '2024-11-30', isPinSet: true, issuedDate: '2020-12-14', lastNumbers: '7231', status: 'TERMINATED', type: 'PHYSICAL', terminationDate: '2021-06-02' } }
  ],
  array2 = [
    {
      dateCreated: '2021-06-02T11:14:27.348Z[UTC]',
      link: 'juan ',
      reason: 'lost card',
      reissueRequest: { link: 'juan ', reason: 'lost card', cardType: 'PHYSICAL', personId: '2576890', adminUser: 'juan@hotmail.com', changePAN: true, lastNumbers: '7231', maintainPIN: false },
      reissuedCard: { state: 'UNACTIVATED', cardId: null, cardType: 'PHYSICAL', isPinSet: true, lastFour: '2377', dateCreated: '2021-06-02', expirationDate: '2025-06-30' }
    }
  ];

const reissuedCardMap = array2.reduce((map, { reissuedCard }) => 
  map.set(reissuedCard.lastFour, { reissuedCard })
, new Map);

const res = array1.map(({ card }) => ({
  card: { ...card, ...(reissuedCardMap.get(card.lastNumbers) || {}) }
}));

console.log(res);
```